# SQL query to display rows that match multiple columns or join multiple rows together based on city-country match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
meta_id post_id     meta_key    meta_value
271     4           _aciudad    New york
270     4           _apais      USA
267     10          _aservicio  Alojamiento

...
261     43          _apais      USA
238     43          _aciudad    Chicago
262     43          _aservicio  Alojamiento
...
261     43          _apais      USA
238     43          _aciudad    Miami
262     43          _aservicio  Alojamiento
```

I need to display all the entries that match Country > City. Or order all the `_aciudad` entries by country; something like:

```
meta_id post_id  meta_key   meta_value       meta_key    meta_value 
235      42      _aciudad        New York     _apais       USA
236      56      _aciudad        Chicago      _apais       USA
237      57      _aciudad        Miami        _apais       USA
238      58      _aciudad        Sidney       _apais      Australia
238      59      _aciudad        Melbourne    _apais      Australia
```

I have no idea how to do this; I guess with an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Is all data in the same table?

Comment: What's the link between miami and Usa? The post_id? But post id 43 has at least 6 records across different _aciudad. Actually, I struggle to see how you got from 238/43/Miami to the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT t1.meta_id, 
           t1.post_id, 
           t1.meta_key, 
           t1.meta_value, 
           t2.meta_key, 
           t2.meta_value 
    FROM table t1, table t2  
    WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
    AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
    AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
    ORDER BY t1.meta_key
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, or if the JOIN ON field is correct because it's not very clear in your question but what about this query?

```
SELECT City.meta_id
     , City.post_id
     , City.meta_key
     , City.meta_value
     , Country.meta_key
     , Country.meta_value
  FROM yourTable City
INNER JOIN yourTable Country ON City.post_id = Country.post_id
WHERE City.meta_key = '_aciudad' AND Country.meta_key = '_apais'
ORDER BY Country.meta_value, City.meta_value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  mc.*, mp.meta_key, mp.meta_value
FROM    meta mc
JOIN    meta mp
ON      mp.post_id = mc.post_id
        AND mp.meta_key = '_apais'
WHERE   mc.meta_key = '_aciudad'
ORDER BY
        mp.meta_value, mc.meta_value
```

Comment: @Richard: maybe, and maybe he wants all cities/countries listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a self-join. To make it work you have to use aliases for the table, so you can refer to it twice.

Something like this:

```
select

  t1.meta_id, t1.post_id,
  t1.meta_key, t1.meta_value, 
  t2.meta_key, t2.meta_value

from TableName t1
  inner join TableName t2
  on t1.meta_id = t2.meta_id and t1.post_id = t2.post_id
    and t1.meta_key = "_aciuidad" and t2.meta_key = "_apais"
```

Comment: The data posted is nonsense, so I guessed. I really think he just needs to be told how to do a self-join, and he will work out the rest for himself.